# Open 3 files in python, add certain columns from each file to dictionaries, combine those dictionaries and filter them against one main file

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I open three different files in python, add certain columns from each file to dictionaries, combine those dictionaries and filter them against one main file?

I was trying to open the file, print the columns I need and then put them into a dictionary. I'm not sure how the syntax works exactly.

```
with open("CSB/python/data/part1.txt", "r")as f:
    for row in reader:
        print(row["col1"], ["col4"])
```

Also, how would I merge those dictionaries and filter it against a master file?

Comment: Could you include a sample of your input and expected output

Comment: So the input is 3 txt files and output would be 1 new files that has 2 specific columns from each txt file filtered against a main file. Do you want me to attach the txt files?

Comment: Show a snippet of your input files, and how the output should look like